# How do I view external function calls in dynamically linked ELF binary in linux?

Tags: gdb, static-analysis, dynamic-analysis, dynamic-linking, objdump

I used the `file` command in Linux to get information about a binary file. I am also looking for the addresses that these calls are located at. I think I can get this information from GDB or `objdump` but I am not very good with Linux commands and programs yet so any help is much appreciated. The output from the file command is below:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x6d232dd468b2344847a4b9c81eb064ffe257d5d0, stripped
```

Then using the `strings` command I got this output (I see several C function calls but which are external ?):

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
-#mH4
__gmon_start__
libc.so.6
_IO_stdin_used
exit
strncmp
strncpy
puts
printf
malloc
atoi
__libc_start_main
GLIBC_2.0
PTRh
QVh>
UWVS
[^_]
testing
strncmp: %s;
atoi
Complete
;*2$"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use nm instead of strings. Undefined symbols (indicated by a `U`) will be resolved externally (by the `libc` or whatever), and `T` (or `t`) symbols are locally defined. Lowercase indicates a local symbol, uppercase a global symbol.

Of course, this assumes there's a symbol table present. In your example, it's been stripped.

In that case, you can do `objdump -T` file to list the external references.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is fairly easy. You can either use the `nm` command with the `-D` switch (or `--dynamic`), or use `objdump` with the `-T` switch. Both commands will output the dynamic symbol table entries and the libraries they originate from.